# Using HandlebarJS with RequireJS, ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, handlebars.js

When loading the handlebarjs using requirejs, I'm getting a `ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined` message.

Here's my config on the app.js file

```
requirejs.config({
    'baseUrl': 'assets/js',
    'paths': {
        'handlebars' : 'plugins/handlebars',
        'controller' : 'controller',
        'initialize'  : 'initialize'
    },
    'shim' : {
        'handlebars': {
            exports: 'handlebars'
        },
        'controller' : {
            deps: [
                'handlebars'
            ]
        }
    }
});

requirejs([
    'handlebars',
    'initialize',
    'controller'
]);
```

On the controller.js file I have this:

```
var source   = $("#entry-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
var ihtml    = template(context);

$('.testad').html(ihtml);
```

But when I wrapped the above code with this, it seems to work:

```
define(['handlebars'], function(Handlebars) {
    // place above code here
});
```

But the problem is, I have methods outside `define()` in which it couldn't be called.

```
define(['handlebars'], function(Handlebars) {
    // place above code here
    function handleMe() {
        // some codes here
    }
});

function callMe() {
    handleMe();
}
```

Another problem is, I have a initialize.js that looks for attribute `my-controller` and calls the functions assigned to it. Somewhat "modularized".

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
$(function() {
    $('[my-controller]').each(function(e, t) {
        var a = $(t).attr('my-controller');
        'undefined' != typeof window[a] && $.isFunction(window[a]) ? window[a]($) : '';
    });
});
```

So in my HTML, if I have `<div my-controller="callMe"></div>`, it will automatically call `callMe()` method wherein it is on my controller.js file. But placing the `callMe()` inside define, it couldn't be called since it won't be global anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the problems you are experiencing have to do with scope.

In your first problem, `handleMe` only exists as a variable within the factory function that wraps it. Nothing outside that closure can see it. It is analogous to this:

```
var fn = function () {
    var a = 1;
};
console.log(a); // undefined
fn(); // a is set, but falls out of scope when the function returns
console.log(a); // still undefined
```

This 'problem' is fixed when you declare your variables in a shared scope (or in the global scope) like this:

```
var a;
var fn = function () {
    a = 1;
}

console.log(a); // undefined
fn(); // a is set in the parent scope
console.log(a) // 1
```

In the second problem, where you are trying to invoke controller methods directly from DOM events, you are doing the same thing except you are trying to access the methods directly from the global scope (`window`).

I suspect that the best solution will be to rethink how you define and organize your modules. In a typical Requirejs project, normally you would define your modules something like this:

```
// Controller.js
define(['handlebars'], function (handlebars) {
    var Controller = function () {
        // Create your controller here. 
        // Create any DOM elements you need here
    };
    Controller.prototype.initialize = function () {
        // Bind the DOM events to controller methods 
    };
    Controller.prototype.method1 = function () {};
    Controller.prototype.method2 = function () {};
    Controller.prototype.method3 = function () {};

    return Controller
});

// main.js
require(['Controller'], function (Controller) {
    var myController = new Controller();

    myController.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Do I have to create a new file for every define()? Like for the given example above with handlebars, should I create controller-handlebar.js file specifically for handlebar logic? And create another file like say, controller-whateverplugin.js? I know that you can make `define(['handlebars', 'whateverplugin'], function (handlebars, whateverplugin) {})` but if dependencies are too many, it would be hard to read. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is one of the biggest advantages of using require, and actually its main purpose (like CommonJS, it is a module /loader/). Every `define()` gets its own file. You also don't need to put 'controller.js' in the `paths:[]` part of your `require.config()`. As long as the name matches (`Controller` === `assets/js/Controller.js`) Require will know where to find it and load it before it is used. Just let it do the work for you. Declarations can get very long, yes, but it only affects the first line of the `define()` and in return you can have a massive code base with no dependency headaches.